# Salesforce very slow in performance

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have use the visual forec page to generate fifty record with each records have 20 . But when the page is loaded, the page is extremely slow. It takes around 50 seconds for the IE to load the page. The viewState is only 50kB. And most of it come from the internal. I would like to ask is there any method to fix this issue?

Comment: is the problem specific to IE or other browsers as well? If only specific for IE - which version of IE?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to use the Force.com Developer Console along with browser developer tools (Chrome provides a timeline tool in it's developer console) to see what is causing the delay.

Once you find the culprit you will have a more specific problem to deal with other than "how do I fix slow code".

Comment: I know it should be due to the too many input field. But it's the internal problem. I don't know how to fix it and replace it with other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well 50k View State is pretty big(considering the limit is 135k) . In your user page enable checkbox for developer mode and for show View State in developer mode and see what is taking so much. For additional tips refer to this [page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State) . 
After seeing you said internal taking most of this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4537/how-to-reduce-a-large-internal-view-state-what-is-in-the-internal-view-state) q&a  might be very helpful.
Shortly try to reduce the use of apex:repeat and similar tags.